# 'Post Your Question' button uses default system font

Tags: bug, design, css

Here is the 'Post Your Question' (or Answer, or 'Add Another Answer') button on my screen:

[image: Answer Button]

<sup>The color being odd is only in the screenshot for reasons beyond my comprehension, it is the proper lighter reddish color on my screen</sup>

The font there is an absolutely hideous Japanese font (I'm on a Japanese OS), and it should ideally be styled with some more appealing font to prevent the ugliness.

Comment: What browser/version/OS are you using? I can't reproduce this bug

Comment: Windows 7 Japanese, Firefox 27.0.1. It also is reproduced in Chrome. Chances are this is an Asian OS only thing, since they often use different fonts designed for double-byte characters as a default. For Font Family the inspector says *"MS UI Gothic"* which is definitely a Japanese font. And it says the option is `-moz-use-system-font` which would explain it. Changing that in the CSS may fix it.